# Pass data from ajax in php

Tags: php, sql, ajax

I want to pass data from ajax. Can anybody please tell me how is that possible??

Here is my index.php

```
   <form method="post" action="">
   <input type="text" id="class_name" name="class_name">
   <input type="hidden" name="user_id" id="user_id" value="<?=$user_id?>" />

   <button id="submit" name="submit" value="submit" type="submit"></button>
   </form>
```

and here is update.php

```
<?
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    user_id= $_POST['user_id'];
    class_name= $_POSt['class_name'];
    $date= date("M d , Y");

    $sql_ins="insert into chat set user_id='$user_id', class_name='$class_name', 
    time=now(),date='$date'";
    $sql_que=$db->db_query($sql_ins);
    }
?>
```

How can I pass this data into server via ajax not from action.??
What is the ajax script for that??
Thanks in advance

Comment: Obviously it is possible use the success method of ajax

Comment: learn jquery and check ajax .. FYR http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Here check this link https://webdesignerhut.com/pass-data-with-ajax-to-a-php-file/

Comment: Is that the correct syntax for `insert into` ??

Comment: @kerbholz This is not the proper syntax for `insert into` `"INSERT INTO chat (user_id,class_name,\`time\`,\`date\`)
    VALUES ('$user_id','$class_name',now(),'$date')"`         Assuming `$date` is in correct format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use jquery with ajax &
call ajax function onclick of submit button

```
$.ajax('URL', {
    type: 'POST',  
    data: { myData: 'formdata' },  // data to submit
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }        
});
```

Comment: can you please describe  data: { myData: 'formdata' },  here myData or formdata

Comment: store formdata values in js variable.
e.g 
var className = $("#class_name").val();

and 
in ajax

data :{classname:className}

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with Jquery:

```
jQuery.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "update.php", //your php file
data: data, //the data of your form
     success: function(html){ 
// this happen after we get result
                              }
   });
```

this is a tutorial: [jquery ajax tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jquery/jquery-ajax.htm)